# Tiff file with Compression Scheme 65100 (0xfe4c)

Tags: compression, adobe, tiff, libtiff

I have a big file (6GB) that displays the following information with libtiff 4.0.3:

```
> tiffinfo MyPic
MyPic: Warning, Nonstandard tile length 1, convert file.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65100 (0xfe4c) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65102 (0xfe4e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65103 (0xfe4f) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65109 (0xfe55) encountered.
TIFF Directory at offset 0x1816881c8 (6466077128)
  Subfile Type: (0 = 0x0)
  Image Width: 20064 Image Length: 306083
  Tile Width: 912 Tile Length: 1
  Resolution: 1, 1 (unitless)
  Bits/Sample: 16
  Sample Format: unsigned integer
  Compression Scheme: 65100 (0xfe4c)
  Photometric Interpretation: min-is-black
  Orientation: row 0 top, col 0 lhs
  Samples/Pixel: 1
  Planar Configuration: single image plane
  Make: ##############
  DateTime: 2013:08:09 08:12:45
  CameraSerialNumber: ###############
  Tag 65100: 1094996812
  Tag 65102: 3
  Tag 65103: 4
  Tag 65109: 1441792
```

As you can see, the file I'm checking contains specific tags (0xfe4c, 0xfe4e, 0xfe4f, 0xfe55), and a compression scheme (0xfe4c) that are "unusual".

After checking some websites, I found that EXIF metadata tags 0xfe4c, 0xfe4e, 0xfe4f, 0xfe55 are Adobe Photoshop's Camera Raw plugin tags [[source](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Image%3A%3AMetaData%3A%3AJPEG%3A%3ATagLists)].

Now, it might be too bald to assume that Compression Scheme 0xfe4c is related to an Adobe program, but, just in case it is, I tagged this with "Adobe".

I cannot provide the image (as it is itself provided by an external company, and weights 6 GB), but can run libtiff commands on it. The issue is that libtiff 4.0.3 doesn't support compression scheme 0xfe4c:

```
> ./tiff2pdf -o /tmp/output.pdf MyPic
MyPic: Warning, Nonstandard tile length 1, convert file.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65100 (0xfe4c) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65102 (0xfe4e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65103 (0xfe4f) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65109 (0xfe55) encountered.
MyPic: Warning, Nonstandard tile length 1, convert file.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65100 (0xfe4c) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65102 (0xfe4e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65103 (0xfe4f) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65109 (0xfe55) encountered.
MyPic: Warning, Nonstandard tile length 1, convert file.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65100 (0xfe4c) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65102 (0xfe4e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65103 (0xfe4f) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65109 (0xfe55) encountered.
MyPic: Warning, Nonstandard tile length 1, convert file.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65100 (0xfe4c) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65102 (0xfe4e) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65103 (0xfe4f) encountered.
TIFFReadDirectory: Warning, Unknown field with tag 65109 (0xfe55) encountered.
tiff2pdf: No support for MyPic with compression type 65100:  not configured.
tiff2pdf: An error occurred creating output PDF file.
```

Has anyone ever encountered this compression scheme?
I don't know if it is a new compression algorithm (in which case I'll either have to reverse-engineer the code, or ask ?Adobe? for support), or if it is a new key for an existing algorithm (in which case, updating my lib would be pretty simple).

Thanks,
Pascal

Comment: raw camera data is not simply RGB data, it's data coming from R, G and B sensors each at a different position in a tiling pattern. To use it properly is not straightforward at all.

Comment: `Samples/Pixel: 1`, e.g., means that R, G and B values are not recognized as such by the library, but will have to be calculated from the knowledge of the positions of the sensors. See, e.g., http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/products/photoshop/pdfs/understanding_digitalrawcapture.pdf

Comment: This file (which I renamed for clarity purposes) is the red channel of a shot.  

As you can see, it should weight 306083 * 20064 * 16 / 8 bytes, which is 11.4 GiB. It

Comment: Its real size is 6466077604 bytes (6.1 GiB). 


A compression has been applied to the file, and that's what I am asking about here. This compression has the code 65100 (0xfe4c) (at EXIF tag 0x0103), which isn't in [this list](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/compression.html) of common compression codes.


Does anyone know what it stands for?

Comment: I see. 65100 is not only absent from that and other lists of compressions, it is also above 65000, and the file also contains private tags in the "reusable" range 65000-65535, (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format#Private_tags). It all looks very "unofficial".